# Is it possible to use App Service to share data between two UWP apps on same network?

Tags: uwp

I have developed a UWP app that uses a database to store data - DB options are MySQL, SQL and SQLite. It functions well. I would like to extend this app into a client server relationship within a network, where the database is managed by a UWP server app. The client app  will then be deployed to several network devices and will be requesting data from the server app.
I know I can can use app service if the apps are on the same device. I would like to know how the use of app service can be extended to a scenario where the apps are not in the same machine but are on the same network. Also, I would appreciate to know if there is a better way of handling intra app communication within a network.

I am aware that the apps could use a connection string to access the database directly but I would like to give an option to those whose only database option is SQLite so that data can be stored centrally and also, avoid keying database credentials with each installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use App Service to share data between two UWP apps on same network?

I'm afraid you can't use App Service to share data between two UWP apps on same network but not in same OS. Derive from offcial [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service)  *App services let you create UI-less services that apps can call on the **same device**.*

For accessing data from other app that be in same network. we suggest you use [stream socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) to approach.